# Magento 2.3.2: Customizable options disappear when saving product programatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-options

I'm running a script that bootstraps Magento to bulk-edit some products programmatically.

At the moment, this is done like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$products = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('paid_shipping')->load();

foreach($products as $product){
  $product->setPaidShipping(1);
  $product->save();
}
```

While this successfully updates the products, the customizable options all disappear. Why does this happen? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you confirm your magento 2 full version?

Comment: @DavaGordon -- 2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that calling `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::save()` directly has been deprecated since Magento 2.1.10 (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.10/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L629).

I have tested saving product using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::save($product)` and your issue did not happen.

Try updating the way you save product using this code:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
 */
$productRepository->save($product)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, will give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @RendyEkoPrastiyo this works, thank you! Any idea why the tax class isn't updated when I use   $product->setTaxClassId(2);
  $productRepository->save($product); ?

Comment: It should also be updated, as tested in Magento vanilla, there must be observer(s) or plugin(s) from external module(s) that handle or modify the tax class upon saving the product.